# How to click on page locators inside TS objects

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom

I am trying to figure it out how to reuse code with object methods. Basically I want to give a string to the method `clickOnModule('Hello word')` and this would click on the given button of the module with that name.

I've tried something like this:

```
class HomePage {
    page: Page;
    helloWorldBtn: Locator;
    modulesList: any;

constructor(page: Page) {
        this.page = page;
        this.helloWorldBtn = page.locator("#hello-world");
        this.modulesList =
            {
              module: "Hello word",
              buttonLocator: function() { return this.helloWorldBtn.click(); }
            },
    // Add other modules to the list
  ];
}

async clickOnModule(moduleName: string) {
  const selectedModule = this.moduleList.find((module) => module.module === moduleName);
  await await selectedModule.buttonLocator();
  }
}
```

I've tried directly defining the button's ID in the DOM directly as a property for `modulesList.buttonLocator` but didn't seem to work as well.

Perhaps I am complicating it too much?

```
class HomePage {
    page: Page;
    helloWorldBtn: Locator;
    modulesList: any;

constructor(page: Page) {
        this.page = page;
        this.helloWorldBtn = page.locator("#hello-world");
        this.modulesList =
            {
              module: "Hello word",
              buttonLocator: this.helloWorldBtn
            },
    // Add other modules to the list
  ];
}

async clickOnModule(moduleName: string) {
  const selectedModule = this.moduleList.find((module) => module.module === moduleName);
  await await selectedModule.buttonLocator.click();
  }
}
```

and

```
class HomePage {
    page: Page;
    modulesList: any;

constructor(page: Page) {
        this.page = page;
        this.modulesList =
            {
              module: "Hello word",
              buttonLocator: page.locator("#hello-world")
            },
    // Add other modules to the list
  ];
}

async clickOnModule(moduleName: string) {
  const selectedModule = this.moduleList.find((module) => module.module === moduleName);
  await await selectedModule.buttonLocator.click();
  }
}
```